# How to integrate a C program runnable terminal to an online coding environment?

Tags: php, node.js, websocket

I have developed an online Coding platform for the most used languages like Java, C, etc. We can give the command/console inputs and get the output. But in this case, it will not hold the UI to get the input. But we need to give all the inputs in the input area and the program will give output accordingly.

[This website](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) is an example. We can enter the program and give the inputs in the "STDIN" tab. The output will be shown in the window.

But I saw two websites, [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) and [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/). Here the UI is holding for the input if we are giving a `scanf` in the  C program. This is not an actual terminal integration. Some `WebSocket` calls are happening to hold and accept the inputs.

I am using `node.js` and `PHP` to create my coding environment. How can I achieve this terminal like behaviour in my program? Can someone help with some existing examples? I am not getting any clue. Did a lot of searches.

Comment: "But in this case it will not hold the UI to get the input" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: @D.B.K, Thanks for asking. If we are running the code through CMD/Terminal, for a C program when scanf used, the terminal will wait to type the input by the user. Can I mock the same thing in a web coding environment like in the link I mentioned above?

Comment: so you don't want to use command line arguments?

Comment: Have you tried using ssh? here is the node ssh package https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh. And here is ssh for PHP https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php. This should help you to achieve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the previous answer, creating a text like terminal in the UI and using chunked encoding to send data back and forth between the api and UI works for me.

The console will run behind your api and certain events like a keypress should trigger an update on the api to send the keypress and an update in the UI to receive the output from the api.

Running a script in the api in the same fashion looks something like:

```
//set header

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octect-stream');

//use chunked encoding (send data in chunks)

res.useChunkedEncodingByDefault = true;

//start process

let proc = child.spawn(cmd, [cmdArgs, cmdOptions]);

//start stream

proc.stdout.pipe(res);

//end stream when process stdout ends

proc.on('exit', () => {
   res.end();
});

//catch errors

req.on('error', function(err){
   console.error(err);
   res.status(500).json({ status: `error`})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, create a terminal like interface and listen to user keypress events..
On the server side, open a pseudoterminal(ptty) and run the required program,..
Make sure you set up the bidirectional flow correctly. i.e, whatever is typed on the UI should be sent and fed to the ptty on the server, and whatever the ptty outputs, it should be displayed on the UI.
The program on ptty will naturally halt and wait if there's any scanf. The user will enter the string in UI terminal, which will be fed to the ptty on the server and the program continues.

Source:
https://dev.to/saisandeepvaddi/how-to-create-web-based-terminals-38d

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. Let me check more on this. Thank you again